# I can't select rows after row number 65536 from excel sheet (Excel 2010)

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to import data from Excel sheet to local DB.(Excel 2010)

Coding is

```
 OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + filePath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;  ImportMixedTypes=Text""");

//Select Row no 1 to 65536
sql = "SELECT F1 FROM [Sheet1$F1:F65536] ";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

//Store into DataTable
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add("Sheet1");
da.Fill(ds, "Sheet1");   

//Name column anme
DataTable table = ds.Tables[tableName];
table.Columns[0].ColumnName = "CODE";

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;   AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Report.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
sqlCon.Open();

//Store result into localDB
SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon);
bulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;

//Map column name "CODE"
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)    
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName.ToString(), column.ColumnName.ToString());  

bulk.WriteToServer(table);
```

But when I try to select row No 65537, I get an error "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$F1:F65537'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$F1:F65537' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."

I also tried ""SELECT F1 FROM [Sheet1$F:F]".
But in table, only fetch 65536 data into table.
Do you have any idea to fetch after row no 65536?

Comment: I don't think you can add any more rows past 65536, as it is the maximum row number supported. A potential solution may be to split it up into separate work sheets.

Comment: Newer versions of Excel can handle far more than 65536 rows.  I don't recall exactly when the limit was raised.  The issue may lie with OleDb.  If this is an .xlsx file, try using EPPlus instead of OleDb.

Comment: It was Excel 2007 in which the row limit was raised to 2^20, which is 1048576 rows, and that limit still remains today.

Comment: if you source is an old Excel file (ie. ends with .xls) then you are limited to the 65536 row limit. Just re-save as an .xlsx

Comment: The connection string is slightly wrong - it should be `Excel 12.0 Xml` instead of `Excel 12.0` in the extended properties

Comment: I found solution. I have changed only quey to  "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " and all data (300,000 data) has been stored.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP:

> I found solution. I have changed only query to "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " and all data (300,000 data) has been stored.